# Проброс портов между двумя роутерами

Tags: сеть, роутер, маршрутизация, порты

Исходные данные:

- Есть два роутера: **Parent** и **Child**.
- Есть сервер
- Локальный IP сервера на роутере **Parent**: `192.168.100.7`
- На роутере **Child**: `192.168.1.33`

Надо открыть порт, например, 9999.

Роутеры подключены следующим образом:

- Есть основной роутер **Parent**, от него идет ethernet провод в роутер **Child** и подключен в разъем "*Интернет*".
- На роутере **Parent** открыт проброс портов для локального IP `192.168.100.7`.

Если к **Parent** подключить сервер - все работает. Открываю проброс портов на роутере **Child** для локального IP `192.168.1.33`. Подключаю сервер к роутеру **Child**, проверяю через 2ip - "порт закрыт".

Вопрос: что пошло не так? Как можно организовать такую систему?

Comment: На Parent пробросить порт на WAN IP роутера Child, на Child - его же на сервер `192.168.1.33`. Сервер должен в качестве шлюза по умолчанию использовать роутер Child.

Comment: @kff Черт, даже стыдно за такую глупую оплошность) Спасибо большое